# why does i2cset send extra bytes?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, i2c

I've been working on PIC18F55K42 chip for a while. The PIC is setup as a slave and it's receiving bytes correctly. But I encountered a few problems.

For example, when I do:

```
i2cset -y 1 0x54 0x80 0x01
```

It looks correct on the controller side and I can see the address 0x80(data address) and byte value 0x01.

When I send in block mode like:

```
i2cset -y 1 0x54 0x80 0x01 0x02 0x03 0x04 i
```

I see spurious bytes appearing on the controller. More precisely, it looks like this:

```
ADDRESS 80 6c 00 2f 01 02 03 04 STOP
```

[image: Salae Logic Analyser trace]

At first I thought this is something to do with my controller and even tried digging into it's clock settings. Used Salae logic analyser too. There's nothing wrong with the controller or it's set up. The only place I can think of is the complex onion driver layering done by Linux.

I'd like to know why Linux is sending the 3 extra bytes (`6c 00 2f`). Why does `i2c_smbus_write_block_data` send extra bytes and how can it be avoided?

Comment: can you just check the driver code?

Comment: @AlexHoppus I lost after I reached [i2c-algo-bit.c](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/i2c/algos/i2c-algo-bit.c). Hence, here :)

Comment: I haven't seen any references that linux could be built for PIC18F55, can you specify the config you are using for building? Are you using mainline kernel or modified one?

Comment: @AlexHoppus It's a modified version. But I think I found the problem. See Reid Lindsay's answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a bug in the `i2cset` implementation in Busybox. See `miscutils/i2c_tools.c`:

```
    /* Prepare the value(s) to be written according to current mode. */
    switch (mode) {
    case I2C_SMBUS_BYTE_DATA:
        val = xstrtou_range(argv[3], 0, 0, 0xff);
        break;
    case I2C_SMBUS_WORD_DATA:
        val = xstrtou_range(argv[3], 0, 0, 0xffff);
        break;
    case I2C_SMBUS_BLOCK_DATA:
    case I2C_SMBUS_I2C_BLOCK_DATA:
        for (blen = 3; blen < (argc - 1); blen++)
            block[blen] = xstrtou_range(argv[blen], 0, 0, 0xff);
        val = -1;
        break;
    default:
        val = -1;
        break;
    }
```

Should be `block[blen - 3] = xstrtou_range(argv[blen], 0, 0, 0xff);`. The bug results in 3 extra garbage bytes from stack being sent.

Comment: Yes, and the bug [was fixed on Oct, 2017](https://github.com/mirror/busybox/commit/b5d9ba8fe64a0aacf99fd1eec10375a98104a5ea#diff-62254ed6bd6e728a4e3321af32358e2cL617). @Unmanned Player -- I use busybox 2018.05 so that this bug already patched for me.

Answer (score 0):

Use `i2c_smbus_write_i2c_block_data` for raw i2c transfers

`i2c_smbus_write_block_data` makes data transfer using SMBUS protocol

Comment: I'm using BusyBox i2c-tools and using the option `i` does call [`i2c_smbus_write_i2c_block_data`](https://github.com/mirror/busybox/blob/master/miscutils/i2c_tools.c#L231)

Comment: Hmm… I have beaglebone, saleale and some i2c chips like lm75 and rtc. Maybe I will probably check it on the weekend.